# VS Code, Live server extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’m doing a tutorial HTML course in VS Code. I made another folder on my pc for my practice project and then created a HTML file which I opened in VS code. When I try to open it with live server extension it opens a Listing directory titled page with my IP address, but doesn’t open my new HTML file in the browser which I created. Also, when I try to open another HTML file with it, it opens the same listing directory page. So the point is basically I can’t open my HTML files with live server.

My question is, how can I open the file with live server so I can see my recent project?

I tried refresh the extention, disable then enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution but a quick one for emergencies (enough for the tutorial):

Install the extension "Open PHP/HTML/JS In Browser".